# Xamarin reactjs webview navigation

Tags: reactjs, xamarin, webview, react-router

I'm trying to detect when the page location changes in a react app using the Xamarin forms webview `.Navigated` event. However, it seems like it's only issued when I navigate to an external page, not within the react app, even though I'm using react router. In my browser, the url changes but the Xamarin webview doesn't register that change, even if I manually poll the url by printing `webView.Source`.

Is there some way I can detect a navigation within the react app from C#?

Comment: What are your urls in react app? Are they hash based?

Comment: They're just static urls using the react router switch statement, e.g. `localhost:3000/page-1`. Based on the example at https://github.com/mlaursen/react-md/tree/master/examples/with-react-router-v4

Comment: you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @shreddish I don't think I did. I ended up abandoning embedding reactjs withing a Xamarin forms app and instead built this app from scratch using the underlying APIs instead, and this was one of multiple reasons for doing that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a component to be location aware, you can wrap it with the HoC [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) provided by [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest `<Route>`'s match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will re-render its component every time the route changes with the same props as  render props: { match, location, history }.

Once you're getting location change updates in your react app you can update your C# to perform any actions you require.

EDIT: To address your comment...

Now I've never used C#, but according to my research this should work.... take a look at `__doPostBack`. You can read about how to use it [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-excecute-a-c-Method-63380306).

Comment: I think the User needs to detect Url changes from react app within C#. Even if you successfully access the location in the children, that will still not solve Xamarin knowing about the location change.

Comment: I'm going to assume they know how to update their c# code from javascript and that react-router is what they don't have experience with

Comment: I don't really have much experience with either, and it doesn't seem like there's a way to call C# from JS with the xamarin forms webview. Looks like I might need to implement platform specific code :(

Comment: the question isn't asking about how to use react router - this is asking why react router `history.push` is not triggering the Xamarin webview `Navigated` event